# How to block block of ip address in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

We have experienced a large number of bad requests from several ip addresses that causes a lot of 404 errors and considerably slow down our page load.  Our environment does not allow us to use htaccess file.  So I am trying to block them in httpd.conf.   Here is the directive that I tried various syntax to block 216.244.75.*   These ips are blocked but they continue to cause error 403.  Though the performance of our website improved a great deal.  Is there a better way to block these IP's completely?

```
<Directory "/home/chariya/webapps/betatest">
  SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "216.244.75" blocked    
  SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "^216\.244\.75\.*" blocked    
  SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "216.244.75.226" blocked    
  SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "216.244.75.162" blocked   
  <RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require not env blocked
  </RequireAll>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to block an ip address in httpd.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58740175/how-to-block-an-ip-address-in-httpd-conf)

Comment: Stuart Frankish  I also tried that, but results are the same.  the IPs were block but still produced a lot of 403 errors.  I am looking for solution where the access were not logged.

Comment: Hiding the logged errors won't make the incoming traffic stop - you need to sit your server or application behind a firewall or other mitigation service if you don't want that traffic to reach you - otherwise the logging of errors is to be expected.

Answer (score 1):

To debug mod_rewrite and products based on Apache 2.2 and below, enable rewrite logging. For example:

```
RewriteLog "logs/rewrite.log" 
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

To debug mod_rewrite and products based on Apache 2.4:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8
```

And check your error logs. This can be helpful to diagnose the problem